# How to input a formula into an empty cell if another cell is not empty in excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have searched through stackoverflow and found a few topics very very similar to mine, but the answers are not specific and usually are just vba code without any explanation of how it works. Below is what I am trying to do.
1. If empty cell is populated (lets say C3)
2. then input formula into another empty cell at AT3
3. =VLOOKUP(C3,'WC Chart'!A3:G351,3,FALSE)  this is my vlookup formula, it works.
I just need it to only populate in the empty cell when c3 has populated text so I need a vba way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this...

```
'This line will place the formula in AT3 only if C3 is not blank
If Range("C3").Value <> "" Then Range("AT3").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(C3,'WC Chart'!A3:G351,3,FALSE)"

'This line will place the formula in AT3 and if C3 is blank, formula will return a blank in AT3
'And if C3 is not blank, the VLookUp formula will return an output
Range("AT3").Formula = "=IF(C3="""","""",VLOOKUP(C3,'WC Chart'!A3:G351,3,FALSE))"
```

Comment: The one variable I forgot to mention is that I have vba code that extracts a row of data onto this sheet into the next available row that has nothing in it at all. It looks like this might work @sktneer, im giving it a try now.

Comment: @MichaelBean You're welcome! Glad it worked as desired.